# Put usercontrol outside the current page on a master page with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, master-pages

I have a ASP.NET MVC solution where I use MasterPage like this :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="contentBody">
                <div id="mainMenu">
                    @Html.Raw(@Html.MainMenu())
                </div>
                 @Html.Raw(@Html.Partial("LoginStatusPartial"))
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <div id="page">
            @Html.Partial("LoginPartial")
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div id="rightPanel">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="content">
        foot [sitename]&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to put a usercontrol in rightPanel and this do only apply when on a specific page.

Is this possible? And if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sections:

```
<div id="rightPanel">
    @RenderSection("RightPanel", required: false)
</div>
```

and then inside the views that need to put something into this section could define it:

```
@section RightPanel {
    <div>@Html.Partial("SomeRightPanel")</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the following in your master:

```
<div id="rightPanel">
    @RenderSection("Name")
</div>
```

Or, if you just want the right panel to display, if you provide the content in your view, use:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Name")) {
<div id="rightPanel">
    @RenderSection("Name")
</div>
}
```

And use it in your views with:

```
@section Name {
    Content
}
```